# How to kill YARN job using Resource Manager REST API

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, kerberos

we have a kerberos enabled EMR cluster. I would like to kill yarn jobs using RM API through an other application.

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"state": "KILLED"}' "http://x.x.x.x:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_id/state?user.name=hadoop"
```

we are getting below error.

> {"RemoteException":{"exception":"ForbiddenException","message":"java.lang.Exception:
> The default static user cannot carry out this
> operation.","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.ForbiddenException"}}

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply use `...?user.name=...` on a kerberized cluster. Instead, your curl should authenticate to RM via SPNEGO, and that means using curl options [`--negotiate`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--negotiate) and `--user :` . You would also need to `kinit` as an authorized user who can actually kill the application (app owner or super-user) before making a REST call.